# How to reduce the view of camera in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, computer-vision, augmented-reality, arkit

I put 180 planes around camera in each 2 degree.The count of plane show in view is deal due to the degree of planes is deal.

How to change the view of camera in ARKit to make the count of plane less than normal?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the view of the camera as it is tightly coupled to physical camera of your device. What you could do is create a shader which will add a section plane.

Answer (score 0):

**To reduce the RGB view produced by ARCamera use [SKCropNode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skcropnode) from SpriteKit framework**:

```
class SKCropNode: SKNode
```

Apple documentation says about it the following:

> SKCropNode masks pixels drawn by its children so that only some pixels are seen